# Windows PowerShell- Basic commands not working on windows 8

Tags: powershell-3.0

The basic commands like 'get', 'import' not working. The following exception is thrown when I try to run the following command in powershell.

```
PS C:\Users\Axiom> get -help
get : The term 'get' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get -help
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (get:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Do I need to add any extra supporting file of something for it to recognize basic commands?

Comment: Any reason you added space after "get" and before "-help"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [Powershell cmdlet](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/tutorial-powershell-cmdlet/) has a format of Verb-Noun. There should not be spaces between 'verb'(Get in this case),'-'and 'Noun'(help in this case).

```
PS C:\Users\Nitesh> Get-Help
TOPIC
    Get-Help

SHORT DESCRIPTION
    Displays help about Windows PowerShell cmdlets and concepts.

LONG DESCRIPTION

SYNTAX
    get-help {<CmdletName> | <TopicName>}
    help {<CmdletName> | <TopicName>}
    <CmdletName> -?
```